# Criteria for embedded key data

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

Good day, guys. I 've come accross a problem with creating criteria and cant sort it out.
Here's my objects:

```
    @Embeddable
    public class Pk {
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "SUBKEY1_ID", nullable = false, 
              referencedColumnName = "ID")
    private SubKey1 subKey1;
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "SUBKEY2_ID", nullable = false, 
              referencedColumnName = "ID")
    prviate subKey2 subKey2;
    ... getters setters
}

 @Entity
    @Table(name = "TABLENAME", schema = "SCHEMANAME")
    @AssociationOverrides({
        @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.subKey1", joinColumns =
        @JoinColumn(name = "SUBKEY1_ID")),
        @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.subKey2", joinColumns =
        @JoinColumn(name = "SUBKEY2_ID"))
    })
    public class Entity1 {
    @EmbeddedId
    private Pk pk = new Pk();
    ... other fields\getters setters
    }
```

So, i want to get some fields of pk.subkey1. 
I wrote criteria to load whole object, and after that, i can get all necessary fields through getters.

```
Criteria criteria = Entity1DAO.instance().createCriteria();
        criteria.createAlias("activity", "activity")
                .createAlias("pk.subKey1", "subKey1")
                .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                        .add(Projections.property("activity.product"))
                        .add(Projections.property("pk.subKey1"))
                        .add(Projections.property("field")))
                .add(Restrictions.eq("activity.prodDate", date))
                .addOrder(Order.asc("pk.subKey1.id"));
```

But here i cant add any restrictions on **pk**.*subKey1* object (for example - i need to restrict records by **subKey1**.*enabled* flag) 
- because criteria dont do any joins of table related to subKey1 object. its ok, i can skip all records where **subKey1**.*enabled* = **false** in java-code, but is's weird.

And now, i tried to create criteria to get not objects, but some certain fields of objects.

```
criteria.createAlias("activity", "activity")
                .createAlias("pk.subKey1", "subKey1")
                .createAlias("subKey1.zone", "zone")
                .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                        .add(Projections.property("activity.product.id"))
                        .add(Projections.property("subKey1.id"))
                        .add(Projections.property("subKey1.zone.id"))
                        .add(Projections.property("zone.description"))
                        .add(Projections.property("dryQty")))
                .add(Restrictions.eq("activity.prodDate", date))
                .add(Restrictions.eq("subKey1.enabled", true))
                .addOrder(Order.asc("pk.subKey1.id"));
```

But criteria doesnt do any joins (there 's only one join for activity field :( ) of necessary tables (**subKey1** and **zone** table) to get data and sql query crushes with exception, that it cant find columns.
(Field *zone* of *subkey1* is object with its own table).

**So, where did i make mistake, how do i refer to fields of objects to be fields of embedded id?**

Comment: Does it make a difference if you do this Criteria criteria = Entity1DAO.instance().createCriteria(Entity1.class);

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution for this?